# How to show a view with 2 columns on the front page?

Tags: 7, views

I need in the front page on my website to show a view with two columns : the left column will show the two latest content from a category, and the same for the right column.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this:

1. Create a block for each of your views, then add the blocks to the
   content area and select to show on front only (all done via block
   UI), and set it side by side via CSS.
2. Create a content type for the front page. Then create a new instance
   of that content type. Run it through panels and choose two column
   layout, then add views of your liking to the left and right panel.
3. Create a content type for the front page. Manage the display of this
   content type via Display Suite and use two column layout. Add a
   dynamic field for each of the left and right columns, and set the
   dynamic field to display a view of your liking.
4. Implement hook_menu_alter for the front page in a custom module.
   Return the output of 2 views_embed_view() calls wrapped in HTML for
   the columns, or in a render array that will suit your layout.
5. Create a content type for the front page or use an existing type.
   Then create a new instance of that content type. Note the path of
   this content (node/ID). In configuration - site information, set it 
   as the front page. Edit this content type's body element, and using 
   the PHP filter embed the views with calls to views_embed_view().

Methods 2 and 3 are in my opinion preferable, with method 5 the least preferable method. Method 1 is perhaps the easiest.